# Accessing Data from a graph on a website using python

Tags: python, graph, urlretrieve

I have generally wondering if it is possible to access data displayed on graphs such as these: https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/

I have looked at the .htm file and other links within this, yet none seem to be containing this. Would anyone know how to retrieve and print information from the graph using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the information from coinmarketcap using their API.

https://coinmarketcap.com/api/

This will allow you to request data from them, sometimes with given parameters (e.g. the currency) and you'll retrieve the data in a JSON format, which  you can then again parse and display with python.

There are plenty of API tutorials out there for python on the web. Good luck!